# Pass variable amount of parameters to local API in a Blazor Server app

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an API controller set up in my Blazor Server app to handle report generation via FastReport:

`ReportController.cs`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{reportName}")]
    public IActionResult GetReport(string reportName)
    {
        string reportPath = String.Format(@"pathtofilehere.frx", reportName);

        //TODO: different export type handling
        string exportType = "application/pdf";
        string exportFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", reportName);

        WebReport web = new();
        web.Report.Load(reportPath);

        web.Report.SetParameterValue("CONN", @"connstringhere");

        //handle parameters here

        web.Report.Prepare();

        MemoryStream stream = new();
        web.Report.Export(new FastReport.Export.PdfSimple.PDFSimpleExport(), stream);

        stream.Position = 0;

        return File(stream, exportType, exportFileName);
    }
}
```

I currently have calls to this handling some minor parameters via query strings in one of my pages, making a `GET` call by navigating to the API route:

`Reporting.razor`

```
<div class="content-container">
    <input type="text" @bind-value="@_startDate" />
    <button @onclick="DoSomething" type="submit">Download File</button>
</div>

@code {
    private async Task DoSomething()
    {
        string report = "report-2";
        string name = _startDate;

        NavManager.NavigateTo(string.Format("api/Report/{0}?name={1}", report, name), true);
    }
}
```

I have a varying amount of parameters these reports will need to accept, such as start date, end date, user id, etc. There's about 40ish parameters total that we currently have built into our existing legacy site that will be built into this. I know I'll be able to generate a query string dynamically in my `DoSomething`, but I would prefer to be able to pass an enumerable object so I don't need to mess with the query string at all. I know I could pass in a JSON object if I was doing a `POST`, but since I need to actually navigate to the URL to download the file, I don't think I can move that direction.

My initial thoughts were to have an App State singleton that can just read the parameters used and then the controller can pull them out, but the singleton would be shared across all users, which would cause some interference if multiple users are trying to generate reports.

I am trying to avoid generating the PDF on the server and then downloading, which is the reason I'm using the API call to download directly from a stream.

FastReport is the easiest thing I've found to actual build and then generate PDFs, but I'm open to other freeware as well.

Comment: Asked allready ,,, `[FromQuery] ClassWith40Properties parameter` .... or directly get query parameters from HttpContext ....

Comment: Question is unclear ... first what is the problem ? creating dynamic query string? from what? you can use dictionary and simply iterate over it and create query string from them (obviously escaping values) (on Blazor/Client side)... on the server side ... as I wrote you may either use ClassWith40Props or iterate query string dictionary

Comment: Store the object containing your params in injected `IMemoryCache` using `Guid.NewGuid` as the key. Then just pass the Guid to your download action, retreive the object from `IMemoryCache` injected into the controller using the key, then delete the cache entry when finished.

Comment: @Austin `IMemoryCache` is a singleton key-value store which will be shared across all connections, which is why you need to use a unique `Guid` when storing the params for a report and then use that unique key to generate and download the pdf in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the parameters for your report generator in an object and stash it in an injected `IMemoryCache` using a unique `Guid` as the key, then pass that key to your controller to retreive the object.

Blazor component:

```
<div class="content-container">
<input type="text" @bind-value="@_startDate" />
<button @onclick="DoSomething" type="submit">Download File</button>
```

```
@code {
[Inject]
IMemoryCache cache;

private async Task DoSomething()
{
    ReportCreationParameters parameters = new ReportCreationParameters
    {
        Report = "report-2",
        Name = "_startDate"
    };

    Guid key = Guid.NewGuid();

    cache.Set(key, parameters);

    NavManager.NavigateTo(string.Format("api/Report/{0}", key), true);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache cache;

    public ReportController(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    [HttpGet("{key}")]
    public IActionResult GetReport(Guid key)
    {
        // Fetch saved parameters from cache.
        ReportCreationParameters parameters = cache.Get<ReportCreationParameters>(key);

        // Remove saved parameters from cache.
        cache.Remove(key);

        string reportPath = String.Format(@"pathtofilehere.frx", parameters.Name);

        //TODO: different export type handling
        string exportType = "application/pdf";
        string exportFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", parameters.Name);

        WebReport web = new();
        web.Report.Load(reportPath);

        web.Report.SetParameterValue("CONN", @"connstringhere");

        //handle parameters here

        web.Report.Prepare();

        MemoryStream stream = new();
        web.Report.Export(new FastReport.Export.PdfSimple.PDFSimpleExport(), stream);

        stream.Position = 0;

        return File(stream, exportType, exportFileName);
    }
}
```